# Silently suggest an edit review in Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I am professionally related to a topic which is described in an article on Wikipedia. Months ago I respectfully added some content to this article, including a quotation and an link to my website. I tried to care about manners and impartiality.

Last week other professional edited this article, deleted my quotation and a piece of text with my point of view, and added quotations and links to his website with labels and adjectives that I don't consider impartial in any way.

I think that this edit is so clearly illicit that any editor would realize and revert or edit it if she/he red it. How can I request that this be done without getting involved? I would not like to see my user name related to such an article discussion. And of course avoiding sockpuppeting and that kind of tactics.

Comment: Wikipedia has a _very_ active editor community. You should bring this up there. I'm sure you're not the first person to be caught in this circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia:Sock puppetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sock_puppetry#Legitimate_uses), creating a separate account for this purpose might be okay:

> Alternative accounts have legitimate uses. For example, long-term contributors using their real names may wish to use a pseudonymous account for contributions with which they do not want their real name to be associated […] If you use an alternative account, it is your responsibility to ensure that you do not violate this policy. Valid reasons include:
>
> […]
>
> - **Privacy**: A person editing an article which is highly controversial within his/her family, social or professional circle, and whose Wikipedia identity is known within that circle, or traceable to their real-world identity, may wish to use an alternative account to avoid real-world consequences from their editing or other Wikipedia actions in that area.

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice that. I would like, however, that any eventual reversion be made by a non novice user. 
Is that what you say, @pnuts ? I'm not sure that I understand your comment.

Comment: @Rober That would go against the whole “the free encyclopedia that *anyone* can edit” thing.